# Dynamic, General Indexing in R

Tags: json, r, indexing

Is there a way to index across many lists, data frames, *etc.*, in R? That is to say, *generally*? For example, you could retrieve a list of the second element of the second element of lists a & b via `c(a[[2]][[2]],b[[2]][[2]])`, but how can you do this without writing the names of each list and the respective indexing brackets?

Input:

```
l1 <- as.list(c(1,2,3,4,5))
l2 <- as.list(c(6,7,8,9,10))
a <- list(l1,l2)

l4 <- as.list(c(1,2,3,4,5))
l5 <- as.list(c(6,7,8,9,10))
b <- list(l4,l5)
```

Desired output:

```
[1] 7 7
```

I know that you could create a list of only upper nested lists - assuming the same naming convention - with this:

```
nol <- objects()
nol <- grep("^[a-z]$", nol, value=TRUE)
```

I just don't know how to apply across this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via `vapply` as follows:

```
vapply(mget(nol), function(x) x[[2]][[2]], FUN.VALUE = double(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

The idea here is that `mget` gives you a list of your objects. you could also create it by `list(a,b)`. And the anonymous function `function(x) x[[2]][[2]]` returns your values.

Comment: Fantastic! One thing: I know that it's a tradeoff, but I found that using `sapply` in place of `vapply` allows it to work with values greater than length 1.

Comment: Alternatively you can adjust `FUN.VALUE` to your needs

Comment: Oh, I didn't fully realize what that was for! Thanks again.